# for the circuit shown in fig. 1 find the maximum power delivered to load RL

Tags: thevenin

[image]

a circuit with 150 v voltage source and multiple resistances and an RL
need help on this question i found the Rth = 25 ohm
but i cant find the Vth

Comment: For homework, we require you to explain in detail what you have done and where you got stuck. I am no expert in this, but I have a gut feeling that some resistors play no role. And I once heared someone mention 'superposition theorem'.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen i tried to use mesh analysis but i dont know if iam working right i took the lower left loop and said that 150 - 40 (I1-I2)=0 and i took a super mesh the two neghibour lower meshes and said that 150 - 10(I-5)-(15I)=0 but i dont know what further can i do .

Answer (score 1):

[image]

i think this would be the correct answer for the 100v is devided between the two resistors